# Using WSDL with Netty

Tags: netty

One of my clients provided me a WSDL generated in Microsoft Visual Studio.
He claims the only way to connect to this WSDL is over TCP/IP.

So I was thinking to use Netty to manage the connection but I'm not sure how to handle the WSDL/SOAP methods in a way which will work best with Netty framework.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the person is mixing up TCP/IP and HTTP, the lower layer protocol for HTTP is TCP/IP! To access WSDL service, you genrally need to use SOAP which is nothing but XML over HTTP. Netty provides HTTP Protocol encoders and decoders. You will need to add your own handlers to handle the incoming XML.

Take a look at the [RestExpress](https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress) project, it is not SOAP but creates web services using Netty. IMHO, you should be using some tried and tested web service framework like axis, jboss-ws, metro, spring-ws etc etc instead of trying to build your own.

Comment: Will this work with Microsoft WCF net.tcp? How do I easily work with SOAP in TCP mode (For Http I can use SoapUI to test my WSDL)

Comment: I found this link what do you think? http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop/java-client-and-wcf-server.html

Comment: The beauty of webservices SOAP WSDL etc is that they are platform and technology(java/.net) independent.. so even though I have not worked with WCF net, if it is a webservice implementation then you can use the client you mentioned in second link